# How to create a VM from a shared image gallery in a different azure customer account

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have setup a Shared Image Gallery and added a VM image to it.  I can provision a new VM in my subscription from it.  A friend wants to use that same image to provision the same VM in his subscription, a totally different Azure account.  He has added me temporarily as an owner to his subscription and I can change directory from my azure portal to access and work with it no problem.

When I try to create a VM, I can't find the gallery in my subscription/account from his subscription (a totally different Azure account).

I have tried making an application registration and even added permissions for the application in his subscription too (contributor).  Still can't see it.

Is this possible at all or am I doing something wrong?

thank you much

Comment: This may help https://blog.nillsf.com/index.php/2021/04/02/setting-up-shared-image-gallery-cross-tenant-using-the-azure-cli/  I haven't tried it, but researching this area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, we have no way to use the portal to deploy a VM from an image in another azure tenant. To create a VM from an image shared between tenants, you must use the Azure CLI or Powershell. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/share-images-across-tenants)

For example

1. create a service principal in the tenant 1
2. Give Tenant 2 access

a. Register the sp into tenant 2

we can implement it by requesting a sign-in using a browser

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Tenant 2 ID>/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<Application (client) ID>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com%2F
```

b. Assign Azure RABC role `Contributor` to the sp

3. Create VM

a. Log into both tenants using the application ID, secret and tenant ID.

```
$applicationId = '<App ID>'
$secret = <Secret> | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$tenant1 = "<Tenant 1 ID>"
$tenant2 = "<Tenant 2 ID>"
$cred = New-Object -TypeName PSCredential -ArgumentList $applicationId, $secret
Clear-AzContext
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $cred  -Tenant $tenant1
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $cred -Tenant $tenant2
```

b. Create VM

```
$resourceGroup = ""
$location = ""
$vmName = ""

# Set a variable for the image version in Tenant 1 using the full image ID of the shared image version
$image = "/subscriptions/<Tenant 1 subscription>/resourceGroups/<Resource group>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/<Gallery>/images/<Image definition>/versions/<version>"

# Create user object
$cred = Get-Credential -Message "Enter a username and password for the virtual machine."

# Create a resource group
New-AzResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroup -Location $location

# Networking pieces
$subnetConfig = New-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name mySubnet -AddressPrefix 192.168.1.0/24
$vnet = New-AzVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Location $location `
  -Name MYvNET -AddressPrefix 192.168.0.0/16 -Subnet $subnetConfig
$pip = New-AzPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Location $location `
  -Name "mypublicdns$(Get-Random)" -AllocationMethod Static -IdleTimeoutInMinutes 4
$nsgRuleRDP = New-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name myNetworkSecurityGroupRuleRDP  -Protocol Tcp `
  -Direction Inbound -Priority 1000 -SourceAddressPrefix * -SourcePortRange * -DestinationAddressPrefix * `
  -DestinationPortRange 3389 -Access Allow
$nsg = New-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Location $location `
  -Name myNetworkSecurityGroup -SecurityRules $nsgRuleRDP
$nic = New-AzNetworkInterface -Name myNic -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Location $location `
  -SubnetId $vnet.Subnets[0].Id -PublicIpAddressId $pip.Id -NetworkSecurityGroupId $nsg.Id

# Create a virtual machine configuration using the $image variable to specify the shared image
$vmConfig = New-AzVMConfig -VMName $vmName -VMSize Standard_D1_v2 | `
Set-AzVMOperatingSystem -Windows -ComputerName $vmName -Credential $cred | `
Set-AzVMSourceImage -Id $image | `
Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -Id $nic.Id

# Create a virtual machine
New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Location $location -VM $vmConfig
```